# How to get results older than 6 months in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I need code that pulls up records of Accounts where last Payment Status was older than 6 months ago. But I'm not quite sure why my DateDiff won't work.

**My code so far:**

```
SELECT A.[AccountId]
      ,[AccountNumber]
      ,[AccountTypeId]
      ,[AccountStatusId]
      ,[CurrentBalance]
      ,[PaymentStatusID]
      ,D.Last_Change

  FROM [Account] A
  INNER JOIN  ( 
               SELECT AccountId
                     ,MAX(Created) Last_Change
               FROM PaymentStatusHistory
               WHERE ToPaymentStatusID IN (1,2,11)             
               GROUP BY AccountId
              ) D
              ON A.AccountID = D.AccountId

  WHERE PaymentStatusID IN (1,2,11)
    AND AccountStatusId IN (1,2)
    --AND DATEDIFF (DAY, GETDATE(), D.Last_Change) > 180  --Need THIS line corrected.

  ORDER BY CurrentBalance DESC, AccountNumber
```

Comment: What do you mean "won't work"? Do you get an error? Or are the results different to what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up the `starting_date` and `ending_date` of your `datediff`.

```
AND DATEDIFF (DAY, D.Last_Change, GETDATE()) > 180
```

`Get_date()`, current date, should be after your `Last_change` date.

Comment: Thank you. I realised my mistake and corrected it. It works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a positive number, try reversing the order of the dates in your `DATEDIFF`.

For example: `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),'20170101')` returns -250. `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'20170101',GETDATE())` returns 250.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the order in the DATEDIFF and it worked.

```
AND DATEDIFF (DAY, D.Last_Change, GETDATE()) > 180
```

This line of code worked and gave me the result as needed.